# List of Lists by Pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists and I would like to create a list of lists but mainting the order, so if I have:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,2]
l2 = [2,3,4,1]
```

I would like to have:

```
ans = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[2,1]]
```

It mantains the order of the indexes

Thank you!

Comment: The builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is almost exactly what you want: `zip(l1, l2)`. To produce the exact output you want, `[[x, y] for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]`

Comment: thank you! just realized how stupid my question was xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `zip`,

```
ans = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]
```

- You can find a good tutorial about zip in [this tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip).

---

In case one of the lists is longer then the other, you can use `zip_longest` (documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)):

```
from iterators import zip_longest
l1 = [1,2,3,2,7]
l2 = [2,3,4,1]
ans = [[a, b] for a, b in zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=0)]
# output: ans = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[2,1],[7,0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,2]
>>> l2 = [2,3,4,1]
>>> ans = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[2,1]]
>>> [list(v) for v in zip(l1, l2)]
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 1]]
>>> assert _ == ans
```

Comment: You have enough reputation to close this as a duplicate. There might be over 10 duplicates of this

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: `izip` is needed for python2 only. In Python 3 the built-in zip does the same job as itertools.izip in 2.x (returns an iterator instead of a list

Using `zip`

```
l1 = [1,2,3,2]
l2 = [2,3,4,1]

zip(l1, l2)
# [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 1)]
```

Note that `zip` return `list` type:

```
type(zip(l1, l2))
# <type 'list'>
```

It means `zip` computes all the list at once, which is not memory efficient when your `l1, l2` is large. For saving memory, using `izip`: `izip` computes the elements only when requested.

```
from itertools import izip
y = izip(l1, l2)

for item in y:
    print(item)
# (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 1)

print(type(y))
# <itertools.izip object at 0x7f628f485f38>
```

Comment: You are using Python 2. The OP explicitly requested [tag:python-3.x], where pretty much everything about this is different. :) (e.g. `itertools.izip` doesn't exist, and `zip` returns an iterator.)

Comment: My bad, I didn't even notice his tag :D

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do following:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,2]
l2 = [2,3,4,1]

ans = zip(l1, l2) #convert to tuples

ans = map(list, ans) #convert every tuples to list

for pairs in ans:
    print pairs
```